# Fill in pdf forms in a website in firefox

Tags: firefox, pdf

I have to fill in some pdf form in a website. The Firefox pdf reader cannot fill in form, it is just a reader. How can I fill in forms in Firefox?

If needed I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @Kulfy according to this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/29304/743263 evince is able to fill in forms

Answer (score 0):

In firefox 91.7.0esr (64-bit) I am able to edit PDF fields e.g. in [this form](http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf). If I then hit the download button, I download a PDF file *with the fields edited*. And unlike Chrome, the fields remain editable so I can repeat the process and perform further edits. Voila!