# Any solution to write equations while filling pdf?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, latex

I was finding a way of how to fill pdf. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29230/is-there-software-that-can-fill-pdf-forms) is some solutions. But I want to fill not only regular texts, but some complex mathematical equations.

So, is there any solution, that will allow me to fill pdfs with latex format or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

[Xournalpp](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp) has a function to add latex formulas, but it can not fill forms.