# Fill & Sign PDF on Ubuntu

Tags: pdf

When using Adobe Reader on a Windows desktop, one can open a PDF and use the `fill & sign` option. This option does not seem to appear on the Ubuntu version of [Adobe Reader](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux). How does one fill and sign PDF documents on a Ubuntu?

Comment: To be clear it is not the Ubuntu version it is the version that Adobe chooses to make for Ubuntu. So I would be asking them.

Comment: You have to install a later version (2015) using`playonlinux` and `Wine`. Please see this link >>> https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2653-Adobe_Acrobat_Reader_DC.html and come back here if you have any problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there software that can fill PDF forms?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29230/is-there-software-that-can-fill-pdf-forms)

Comment: To make that clear: What you're asking is not actually (securely) signing a document, it is pasting a picture of a signature and saving it. Those two are not the same and should never be confused, although they constantly are. Once you paste a picture of your signature and distribute it, anyone with a computer can copy/paste it anywhere else, and no law can change that.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

### Using Xournal or Xournal++

> How does one fill and sign PDF documents on a Ubuntu?

Not with Adobe unless you get them to add support for it.

Alternatives:

- Install and open Xournal:

  ```
  sudo apt install xournal
  ```
- Or install and open Xournal++, sometimes written `xournalpp`:

  ```
  sudo apt install xournalpp
  ```

(See [this](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp.github.io/pull/23/files) for a comparison between the 2; xournal++ is a rewrite of xournal)

and then ...

- Choose "Annotate PDF" from the File menu and select the PDF to sign.
- Click the "Image" button in the toolbar
- Click on document
- Select an image of your signature
- Optional: export to PDF so you have a new copy

[image: Screenshot of Xournal]

Comment: Unfortunately and inexplicably this didn't work for me, after selecting the image nothing happened. I wasn't even able to add a simple text for what matters with this tool.

Comment: Works for me :-)

Comment: This works but does not create an identity-certified signature as Adobe Acrobat does.

Comment: This works for me. Although I have been using xournal++ and as a last step "Export to PDF".

Comment: @user5534993 neat. https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp.github.io/pull/23/files has a list of differences.

Comment: Upvote for Xournal++! This software works smoothly and inutitive

Comment: Amazing indication

Comment: If Xournal++ is supported, and Xournal is unsupported, should Xournal++ be recommended first?

Comment: That is up to each of us to decide I would assume. But I would assume xournal should be replaced by ++. It's 7 years old but it does pass the build check for 23.10. So maybe it is just that good ;)

Answer (score 10):

I managed to achieve using pre-installed **LibreOffice Draw**.

### Open the file using LibreOffice Draw

1. Right click on the file
2. Click: *"Open with other application"*
3. Type: `draw` and select *"LibreOffice Draw"*

### Insert the picture of your signature

1. From the top menu of Draw, click *Insert*
2. Click *image...*
3. Select an image of your signature
4. Resize and drag where you need it

### Export to PDF

This can be done either from the *red PDF icon* on the right side of the printer icon in the top left corner, or from:

*File, Export As..., Export Directly as PDF*

Comment: I opened a basic PDF doc this way, and right away the page dimensions were off (paragraphs bleeding off the page edge). So... I'm gonna explore something else (online PDF tools).

Comment: @MarsAndBack - for some reason `xournal` worked for me too some time later. I think it was a different installation, but I can't tell you anything particularly useful on how I got it working. Best of luck

Comment: if `apt` doesn't work, try `snap` or maybe from the website?

Comment: Works really well. This is also a way to edit the text or even adjust line spaces. I was asked to remove line space before for a PDF book. Using LibreOffice Draw seems to be a better way.

Answer (score 3):

I did like this:

1. Create my signature with [signaturely](https://signaturely.com/signature-downloaded) and download image as png.
2. Install [Sejda](https://www.sejda.com/), a PDF editor for Linux, macOS and Windows, with a graphical user interface.
   Download deb file from https://www.sejda.com/desktop, then install sejda, like this:

```
sudo dpkg -i sejda-desktop_7.5.4_amd64.deb
```

3. Start sejda and paste the signature image to a pdf.

Answer (score 3):

I made a tool for this: https://github.com/svenssonaxel/pdf-sign

Unlike Xournal++ and LibreOffice Draw, it will keep the quality of the signature (no rasterization), and IMO is faster too since it's specifically made for this use case.

Comment: This is great ! Thank you for this great software :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sign a pdf using https://dochub.com/.  The service was free and worked great!  When I opened the pdf from my google drive, I selected the option to sign using dochub.  I uninstalled Adobe from my Linux machine as the signing part never worked right from Snap.